# Android send shopping card order e-mail with attachments without using intent

Tags: android, android-intent, jakarta-mail, gmail-api, sendmail

- I've developed an Android app with a self developed shopping cart. At the end of the purchase process I want to send an automatic email to the store owner in order to proceed with order.
- Till now I used an email intent in order to force the user to send an email by themselves but the store owner got too many complaints from the users. So now I'm searching for another solution in order to do it in the background.
- I've searched around but didn't find a proper solution. The email should contain a bit of text information along with 1-n attachments from users phone.

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Proper solution would be to send it through web service. But if you want to do it through email in background of your app you must provide possibillity to sign in to email address and send it, it would be like creating another email client. 
Think about creating web service to which you will send these orders it  is way better solution than sending emails from background of your app.

Comment: So could you suggest me an article or tutorial of how to do it with web service? I've searched before that a REST API to use (a one to create an email) but didn't found a proper one.